# proper promisification in bluebird

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, promise, bluebird, node-streams

I have a roughly following code (meta CoffeeScript):

```
xml = new ...
Promise.promisifyAll xml

allRecords = []
xml.on 'frequentTag', (item) ->
   ...

   iPromise = /* some promise made from item */

   allRecords.push iPromise

xml.onAsync('end').then -> Promise.settle allRecords
```

And now the question: can I get rid of `allRecords` accumulator?

Comment: You can't really. `xml` seems to offer a stream interface, which probably has no method to do this accumulation automatically. Maybe you could include a link to the particular library you're using so we can investigate?

Comment: It's an [xml-stream](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream), but I didn't think the question was specific to a particular implementation.

Comment: Any feedback or update on your progress?

Comment: The answer still has the `results` accumulator, moved into outside definition, so I am where I was.

Answer (score 0):

A promise represents a *single* value. It's one value.

There is no trivial way to promisify an event emitter since it does not offer a standard contract like node style callbacks for a single value - since different events get called multiple times.

Doing `Promise.promisifyAll` on an `EventEmitter` will simply not produce meaningful results on its own, and you'd have to promisify it manually. The good news is that if you happen to do this often you can either extract it to a function yourself or use Bluebird's `promisifyAll` with a promisifier argument and have it do the traversal for you.

Bluebird has no knowledge of your event emitter and the contract it defines about when callbacks are called and how. Assuming it ends with an `end` event, errors with an `error` event data flows in with a `frequentTag` event - I'd do something like:

```
xmlProto.prototype.getTags = function getTags(){
     // if you do this very often, this can be faster
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
         var results = [];
         this.on("error", reject);
         this.on("frequentTag", function(item){
              iPhomise = /* some promise made from item */
              results.push(iPromise);
         });
         this.on("end", resolve.bind(null, results));
     }.bind(this)).settle(); // settle all
};
```

Where xmlProto is whatever you're `new`ing, this would let you do:

```
xml = new ...
xml.getTags().then(function(records){
    // work with records
});
```

This can be extracted into a general function for this sort of event emitter - but you get the general idea.